# Sitecore SXA Events Component

Tags: sxa

I am using sitecore 10.1 with SXA, when using the Events components its shows the date time with server timezone regardless the client timezone, is there an option that allows the date\time displayed to be converted to the client timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event List component is using Rendering Variants to render all the fields. To render a date it is using default Sitecore `FieldRenderer` so it is server site date.

Using client-side time settings would require some custom implementation. You could for example implement your own:

- Token
- Scriban

which would take the client timezone and replace existing Variant Date items.

[image]